# java card 3.0.4 applet installation error

Tags: javacard

when I install the applet on my java card the result is this error:

APDU 00C00000 lc: 00 cmdData:  le: 13 expStatus: ????
Response: '027100000E0A00000000000128450000016A88'
Status:   '9000'

Additional response data received: 016A88 but expected: '019000' '016101'

I'm using SimAllianceLoader_v2 for installation.

my applet installed correctly on java card 2

Answer (score 1):

the problem solved somehow.
first problem was that all the used libraries was not compatible with java card 3.0.4
the second problem was with another installed applet even though the aid was different, but just one of this two custom applets could be installed on the sim card.